# Why does `:=` work as an infix operator?

Tags: r, syntax

Why does the following work in R?

```
> `:=` <- function(x, y) x + y
> 1 := 2
[1] 3
```

My understanding was that `%` was required for user-defined infix operators.  Are there other (possibly easier to type) options available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `:=` is, like `<-` or `<<-`, defined as `LEFT_ASSIGN` for the parser of R. 
See http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/gram.y

This means that `:=` is a special case and you may as well not expect that any other options are available.

Comment: It is rather weird that you can mask existing non-% infix operators with ridiculous definitions.

Comment: What is more weird for me is that `:=` is defined only for the parser, but definition of `:=` is absent.

Comment: Thanks @kohske.  Looking at that code, it appears that `:=` is the only "spare" token recognised by the parser.

Comment: Seen in the wild [here](http://code.google.com/p/miscell/source/browse/rvalues/rvalues.r).  It's being used for a multiple assignment operator, which kind of makes sense.

Comment: This is also used in the `data.table` package.